# Oracle SQL - ORA-04079: invalid trigger insert

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to create a trigger that runs when I insert in table 'cuenta' and make an insert in table 'cuenta_log', one of the values of this insert is gotten by accept input.

```
create or replace trigger trigger_new_account                
    AFTER INSERT ON cuenta  FOR EACH ROW
    accept vstring prompt "Please enter your name: ";
    declare v_line varchar2(50);
    begin
        v_line:= 'Hello '||'&vstring';
        insert into cuentas_log (fecha,cuenta,cliente)
        values (now(),:new.idcuenta,v_line);

    end;
```

cuenta_log structure is like that:

```
cuenta_log 
 ("FECHA"   DATE DEFAULT (sysdate), 
  "CUENTA"  NUMBER(38,0),   
  "CLIENTE" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
 )
```

Comment: What error you get ?

Comment: ORA-04079:00000 -  "invalid trigger specification", *Cause:  The create TRIGGER statement is invalid. *Action:  Check the statement for correct syntax.

Comment: firstly, instead of 'new' you should use ':new'.

Comment: secondly, format your code, it looks terrible.

Comment: OK, edited, thank you. But I have still the same problem.

Comment: i guess then you cant make things like: `accept vstring prompt "Please enter your name: ";`
In a trigger.
If you want username, you can use `user` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger fires on certain *event*; yours, after insert into table named `cuenta`. It doesn't work *interactively* with end users. You can't expect it to prompt anyone to enter anything. Besides, `accept` is a SQL*Plus command, it won't work in PL/SQL.

So, here's what you might have done: sample tables first:

```
SQL> create table cuenta (fecha date, cuenta number);

Table created.

SQL> create table cuenta_log (fecha date, cuenta number, cliente varchar2(30));

Table created.
```

Trigger:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trigger_new_account
  2    after insert on cuenta
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    insert into cuenta_log(fecha, cuenta, cliente)
  6    values
  7    (sysdate, :new.cuenta, 'Hello ' || user);
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into cuenta (fecha, cuenta) values (sysdate, 100);

1 row created.

SQL> select * From cuenta;

FECHA                   CUENTA
------------------- ----------
11.05.2020 12:31:17        100

SQL> select * From cuenta_log;

FECHA                   CUENTA CLIENTE
------------------- ---------- ------------------------------
11.05.2020 12:31:17        100 Hello SCOTT

SQL>
```